# how to read multiple specific columns out of compressed .csv file in R

Tags: r, performance, csv, io, compression

I need a fast way to read multiple specific columns from a .csv file compressed as `.tar.gz` into a variable in R.

My approach:

```
con <- textConnection(system(paste("zcat ", filename.tar.gz, " | cut -d ; -f 1,2,3", sep = "")))
var <- read.csv(con, sep = ";")
```

it seems like he does not understand the pipe command, since it `zcat filename.tar.gz | cut -d ; -f 1,2,3` is working on console.

The error i'm getting in R:

```
[5] "cut.gz: No such file or directory"                                                                                                                     
[6] ";.gz: No such file or directory"                                                                                                                       
[7] "2.gz: No such file or directory"
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) pipe** If we have a csv file named `a.csv` in `a.tar.gz` and it has 8 columns and we want to read the first 3 columns and ignore the rest (or in place of using `colClasses` use a pipeline in `pipe` as in your question):

```
read.csv(pipe("tar -xOzf a.tar.gz a.csv"), colClasses = rep(c(NA, "NULL"), c(3, 5)))
```

**2) gsubfn** To parameterize it, it could be written like this:

```
library(gsubfn)

Archive <- "a.tar.gz"
File <- "a.csv"

read.csv(fn$pipe("tar -xOzf $Archive $File"), colClasses = rep(c(NA, "NULL"), c(3, 5)))
```

**3) fread**   The `fread` function in data.table can also be useful here.  This uses `Archive` and `File` from (2).  It has the advantage of not requiring knowledge of the number of columns.  Also `fread` handles shell commands directly, can usually figure out whether there are headers and what the separator is and it tends to be fast.

```
library(data.table)
library(gsubfn)

fn$fread("tar -xOzf $Archive $File", select = 1:3)
```

Comment: I do not just want to read a .csv file. I want to read the content of the .csv while it is compressed in a .tar.gz file

Comment: Sorry for my short answers, but the reason behind not untar'ing it is that just want to have one or two columns out of a 3 gb big file.

Comment: You can use `pipe`.  See revision.